# Ordered List and Sublist issue HTML

Tags: html, nested-lists, html-lists

So here is my code:

```
      <div class="faq">
      <br />
<ol>
<li>Frequently asked questions about Sweden</li>
<li><a href="#faq1">What and where is Sweden?</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#faq2">When did Sweden stop participating in wars?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#faq3">Is Sweden a part of the European Union?</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#faq4">Did Sweden ever have a scientific revoution?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#faq5">Did the Nobel Prize really come from Sweden?</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <li>More Questions
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#faq6">Does Sweden hold many patents on their inventions?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#faq7">How does the Swedish educational system work?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#faq8">How is school financed in Sweden?</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

When I then use this code, the first list called, "Frequently asked questions about Sweden" has its roman numeral (the one given to it from the ordered list) on the wrong side of it.
So basically it looks like this:

Frequently asked questions about Sweden.           II.

When it should look like:

II. Frequently asked questions about Sweden.

I dont know how to put it at the start of the question. All the other lists and sublists act fine but this one messes up somehow.....
Help please :)

Comment: i think it's related to your css - can you post the definintion for the class "faq"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

1. Frequently asked questions about Sweden
  - What and where is Sweden?
  - When did Sweden stop participating in wars?
  - Is Sweden a part of the European Union?
  - Did Sweden ever have a scientific revoution?
  - Did the Nobel Prize really come from Sweden?
2. More Questions

   - Does Sweden hold many patents on their inventions?
   - How does the Swedish educational system work?
   - How is school financed in Sweden?

```
<html>
<head>
</Head>
<body>
<ol> 
    <li>Frequently asked questions about Sweden</li> 
<ul>
    <li><a href="#faq1">What and where is Sweden?</a></li>     
    <li><a href="#faq2">When did Sweden stop participating in wars?</a></li>     
    <li><a href="#faq3">Is Sweden a part of the European Union?</a></li>            
    <li><a href="#faq4">Did Sweden ever have a scientific revoution?</a></li>             
    <li><a href="#faq5">Did the Nobel Prize really come from Sweden?</a></li>  
</ul>
    <li>More Questions         
<ul>             
    <li><a href="#faq6">Does Sweden hold many patents on their inventions?</a></li>             
    <li><a href="#faq7">How does the Swedish educational system work?</a></li>             
    <li><a href="#faq8">How is school financed in Sweden?</a></li>         
</ul>            
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it is, however, the "1" that is in front of the first line, "Frequently asked questions about Sweden" appears behind it.

Frequently asked questions about Sweden                    1 
is what it looks like

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  The code I provided places the '1' at the start of the line.  Is it not working for you?

Comment: its hard to explain, specially since I am not yet allowed to upload pictures yet. But I made use of your code, but somehow, on the first line, the number 1 always ends up behind the statement or line.

try this link [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/830/41936929.png/)

Comment: When using the shorthand property, the order of the values are:

list-style-type 
list-style-position (for a description, see the CSS properties table below) 
list-style-image 
It does not matter if one of the values above are missing, as long as the rest are in the specified order.

If you are specifying the LIST-STYLE-POSITION, ckeck your CSS to see how it specifies the list-item markers -- whether they should appear inside or outside the content flow

Comment: Sorry, the table didn't print but the order should be: (1) list style type, (2) list style position and then (3) list style image

Comment: You can also use a type attribute for the sublist to make it so it is also ordered (but with a different scheme), if you wanted to do that. [Here is the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_type.asp) for it.